# Fast comparison of two doubles ignoring everything that comes after 6 decimal digits

Tags: c#, performance, double, precision

I try to optimize the performance of some calculation process.
Decent amount of time is wasted on calculations like the following:

```
var isBigger = Math.Abs((long) (a * 1e6) / 1e6D) > ((long) ((b + c) * 1e6)) / 1e6D;
```

where "a","b" and "c" are doubles, "b" and "c" are positive, "a" might be negative.

isBigger should be true only if absolute value of "a" is bigger than "b+c" disregarding anything after the 6th decimal digit.

So I look at this expression, I understand what it does, but it seems hugely inefficient to me, since it multiplies and divides compared numbers by million just to get rig of anything after 6 decimal places.

Below is the program I used to try and create a better solution. So far I failed.
Can someone help me?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var arrLength = 1000000;
        var arr1 = GetArrayOf_A(arrLength);
        var arr2 = GetArrayOf_B(arrLength);
        var arr3 = GetArrayOf_C(arrLength);
        var result1 = new bool[arrLength];
        var result2 = new bool[arrLength];


        var sw = new Stopwatch();

        sw.Start();
        for (var i = 0; i < arrLength; i++)
        {
            result1[i] = Math.Abs((long) (arr1[i] * 1e6) / 1e6D) 
                         > 
                         (long) ((arr2[i] + arr3[i]) * 1e6) / 1e6D;
        }
        sw.Stop();
        var t1 = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;

        sw.Restart();
        for (var i = 0; i < arrLength; i++)
        {
            //result2[i] = Math.Round(Math.Abs(arr1[i]) - (arr2[i] + arr3[i]),6) > 0; // Incorrect, example by index = 0
            //result2[i] = Math.Abs(arr1[i]) - (arr2[i] + arr3[i]) > 0.000001; // Incorrect, example by index = 1
            //result2[i] = Math.Abs(arr1[i]) - (arr2[i] + arr3[i]) > 0.0000001; // Incorrect, example by index = 2
            result2[i] = Math.Abs(arr1[i]) - (arr2[i] + arr3[i]) > 0.00000001; // Incorrect, example by index = 3
        }
        sw.Stop();
        var t2 = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;

        var areEquivalent = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < arrLength; i++)
        {
            if (result1[i] == result2[i]) continue;

            areEquivalent = false;
            break;
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Functions are equivalent : {areEquivalent}");
        if (areEquivalent)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Current function total time: {t1}ms");
            Console.WriteLine($"Equivalent function total time: {t2}ms");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press ANY key to quit . . .");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static readonly Random _rand = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
    private const int NumberOfRepresentativeExamples = 4;

    private static double[] GetArrayOf_A(int arrLength)
    {
        if(arrLength<=NumberOfRepresentativeExamples) 
            throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(arrLength)} should be bigger than {NumberOfRepresentativeExamples}");

        var arr = new double[arrLength];

        // Representative numbers
        arr[0] = 2.4486382579120365;
        arr[1] = -1.1716818990000011;
        arr[2] = 5.996414627393257;
        arr[3] = 6.0740085822069;

        // the rest is to build time statistics
        FillTheRestOfArray(arr);

        return arr;
    }
    private static double[] GetArrayOf_B(int arrLength)
    {
        if(arrLength<=NumberOfRepresentativeExamples) 
            throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(arrLength)} should be bigger than {NumberOfRepresentativeExamples}");

        var arr = new double[arrLength];

        // Representative numbers
        arr[0] = 2.057823225;
        arr[1] = 0;
        arr[2] = 2.057823225;
        arr[3] = 2.060649901;

        // the rest is to build time statistics
        FillTheRestOfArray(arr);

        return arr;
    }
    private static double[] GetArrayOf_C(int arrLength)
    {
        if(arrLength<=NumberOfRepresentativeExamples) 
            throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(arrLength)} should be bigger than {NumberOfRepresentativeExamples}");

        var arr = new double[arrLength];

        // Representative numbers
        arr[0] = 0.3908145999796302;
        arr[1] = 1.1716809269999997;
        arr[2] = 3.9385910820740282;
        arr[3] = 4.0133582670728858;

        // the rest is to build time statistics
        FillTheRestOfArray(arr);

        return arr;
    }
    private static void FillTheRestOfArray(double[] arr)
    {
        for (var i = NumberOfRepresentativeExamples; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = _rand.Next(0, 10) + _rand.NextDouble();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cutting off precision will not increase performance. If anything the extra rounding step will cost performance. This might be a case where you want fixed precision however (6 digits). For those you can not use double or float. Usuall workarounds include a Fixed Precision Decimal type. or just storing and processing as a Int, only adding the decimal seperate during printout.

Comment: I also feel compelled to link the Perforamce rant. Because you might be doing micro-optimisations where none are needed: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the linked article! But nope, I come here after I used profiler already, and this kind of calculation is important performance-wise. Regarding cutting precision: this is not the case. These boolean values are calculated to decide the following code flow, ignoring anything that comes after the 6th digit is a result of some physics. (Something falls below the noise)

Comment: Multiplication and division are really fast nowadays especially when kept as `double` and the numeric co-processor takes over. What is at least an order of magnitude slower is memory access, so the array lookups may be at fault here. Try to cache the values used in local variables if they are going to be used multiple times.

Comment: In `result1` the `Math.Abs()` function only applies to `arr1[]`. Is this correct? Are you checking `|a| < (b+c)` but with 6 significant digits? Because in your tries you apply the absolute value to all the values `| a - (b+c) |` and that is different.

Comment: I am voting to close this question because it is unclear if the correct answer is one that shows a speedup, or one that correctly compares two numbers with 6 significant digits. @user3053953 needs to edit the question and clarify the goal of the posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the division since if `(x/100) < (y/100)` that means that `x<y`.

```
for(var i = 0; i < arrLength; i++)
{
    result2[i] = Math.Abs((long)(arr1[i] * 1e6)) 
                    > (long)((arr2[i] + arr3[i]) * 1e6);
}
```

with the results for me:

```
Arrays have 1000000 elements.
Functions are equivalent : True
   Current function total time: 40.10ms 24.94 kflop
Equivalent function total time: 22.42ms 44.60 kflop
A speedup of 78.83 %
```

PS. Make sure you compare *RELEASE* versions of the binary which includes math optimizations.

PS2. The display code is

```
Console.WriteLine($"Arrays have {arrLength} elements.");
Console.WriteLine($"Functions are equivalent : {areEquivalent}");
Console.WriteLine($"   Current function total time: {t1:F2}ms {arrLength/t1/1e3:F2} kflop");
Console.WriteLine($"Equivalent function total time: {t2:F2}ms {arrLength/t2/1e3:F2} kflop");
Console.WriteLine($"An speedup of {t1/t2-1:P2}");
```

Comment: Does keeping the long cast improve performance still further? Also, the rounding direction is different for negative numbers, so behaviour will be changed for certain cases.

Comment: Hm...  why shouldn't I use cast to long? if I do the following : result2[i] = (long)Math.Abs(arr1[i] * 1e6) > (long)((arr2[i] + arr3[i]) * 1e6); I get even better results...  but I am not sure about memory wasted

Comment: @user3053953 - Really, I would think `Math.Floor()` would be faster. Also, the treatment of negatives is zero. I am updating my post to remove the `Floor()` function.

Comment: * here is a link to online port of this code to [Fortran](https://www.jdoodle.com/a/PTN) for reference. The speedup over `c#` on my machine is 5000×.

Comment: This was the key for the answer. Improved code is in separate post below.

Answer (score 1):

Overall your question goes into the Area of Realtime Programming. Not nessesarily realtime constraint, but it goes into teh same optimisation territory. The kind where every last nanosecond has be shaved off.

.NET is not the ideal scenario for this kind of operation. Usually that thing is done in dedicated lanagauges. The next best thing is doing it in Assembler, C or native C++. .NET has additional features like the Garbage Collector and Just In Time compiler that make even getting reliable benchmark results tricky. Much less reliale runtime performance.

For the datatypes, Float should be about the fastest operation there is. For historical reasons float opeations have been optimized.

One of your comment mentions physics and you do have an array. And I see stuff like `array[i] = array2[i] + array3[i]`. So maybe this should be a matrix operation you run on the GPU instead? This kind of "huge paralellized array opeartions" is exactly what the GPU is good at. Exactly what drawing on the screen **is** at it's core.

Unless you tell us what you are actually doing here as sa operation, that is about the best answer I can give.

Comment: Thanks mate, agree with what you say. But, I am not given a lot of time. Just a working code and profiler. Which took me to some function, 40% cpu time used on it, and about 60% of this function time is wasted on 6 calculations like this. So, this is the easiest short-term fix. As for array, there is no such in working code. I used array in test program to actually measure time on something.

Comment: It sounds like teh code runs about as fast as it can. About the only improovement I can think off would be to add some Multitasking to at least not block the GUI thread. Beyond that this is simply how long this code takes. If something as [2O] or [O^2] complexity, that is how long it takes.

Comment: I agree with these comments. I did a test with Fortran and the same calculation yields `250 Mflops` of naive code (simple loops, no parallelization) as opposed to `50 kflops` that `C#` code produces in the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
Math.Abs(a) - (b + c) > 0.000001
```

or if you want to know if the difference is bigger (difference either way):

```
Math.Abs(Math.Abs(a) - (b + c)) > 0.000001
```

(I'm assuming you're not limiting to this precision because of speed but because of inherent floating point limited precision.)

Comment: Both your examples will fail the test program, those are not equivalent to the initial code.

Comment: @user3053953 As far as I can tell it fits `isBigger should be true only if absolute value of "a" is bigger than "b+c" disregarding anything after the 6th decimal digit.` if we assume the point is precision. Can you give me an a, b, and c for which this is wrong?

Comment: Why don't you just run the test program? Use second "for" block to test your solution. Put a breakpoint in the third "for" block to get you an example of a,b and c.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to asking this question on this site, I also asked a good friend of mine, and so far he provided the best answer. Here it is:

```
result2[i] = Math.Abs(arr1[i]) - (arr2[i] + arr3[i]) > 0.000001 || 
             Math.Abs((long)(arr1[i] * 1e6)) > (long)((arr2[i] + arr3[i])*1e6);
```

I am happy to have such friends :)

Comment: How is this the best answer if you do not provide the speedup in the calculation. Also, the comparison is different from the original posting. For _some_ values, it will produce identical results, but for some, it won't. There isn't enough information posted to effectively answer.